# python creating a 2d array/dataframe with variable row elements

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dataframe, time-series, vectorization

I have a timneseries over a number of days where for each day, I have a variable number of datapoints. A sample dataframe is generated bwlow:

```
n=10,20
init=datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 24, 0, 0)
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in np.arange(n[0],n[1]):
    s =init+datetime.timedelta(days=i-10)
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(i) ,index= pd.date_range(s, periods=i, freq='T') )])
```

Given a dataframe like the one above, I was to create another dataframe/ndarray which has index= dates from above df (not applicable in case of ndarray). And values(rows) = concatenated data of the previous 2 days (since all rows will have different length using this, we can use "NA" to make them equal)

I tried doing this:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'))
d = {k: v for k, v in g}
k=d.keys()
k.sort()
X=pd.DataFrame(index=k)
for i in np.arange(1,len(k)):
    X.ix[i]=pd.concat([d[k[i]],d[k[i-1]]]).ix[:,0]
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi  @dayum could you explain the concatenation part and the structure of one days data

Comment: Hi, the first part is just given as a ref to show how my dataframe looks like. It is not otherwise involved in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy, loops are necessary:

```
import datetime as datetime
n= 1,5
np.random.seed(1)
init=datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 24, 0, 0)
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in np.arange(n[0],n[1]):
    s = init+datetime.timedelta(days=int(i)-10)
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({"col": np.random.rand(i)}, 
                                     index= pd.date_range(s, periods=i, freq='T'))])
print (df)    
                          col
2016-07-15 00:00:00  0.417022
2016-07-16 00:00:00  0.720324
2016-07-16 00:01:00  0.000114
2016-07-17 00:00:00  0.302333
2016-07-17 00:01:00  0.146756
2016-07-17 00:02:00  0.092339
2016-07-18 00:00:00  0.186260
2016-07-18 00:01:00  0.345561
2016-07-18 00:02:00  0.396767
2016-07-18 00:03:00  0.538817
```

Create all unique days by [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
u = np.unique(np.array(df.index.values.astype('<M8[D]')))
print (u)
['2016-07-15' '2016-07-16' '2016-07-17' '2016-07-18']
```

Then create all values by loops to `dict` `d` by [`datetimeindex partial string indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing):

```
d = {}
for i in u:
    dat = str(i)
    dat1 = str((i - pd.Timedelta('1D')))
    d[i] = pd.Series(df.loc[dat1:dat, 'col'].values)

print (d)
{numpy.datetime64('2016-07-18'): 0    0.302333
1    0.146756
2    0.092339
3    0.186260
4    0.345561
5    0.396767
6    0.538817
dtype: float64, numpy.datetime64('2016-07-15'): 0    0.417022
dtype: float64, numpy.datetime64('2016-07-16'): 0    0.417022
1    0.720324
2    0.000114
dtype: float64, numpy.datetime64('2016-07-17'): 0    0.720324
1    0.000114
2    0.302333
3    0.146756
4    0.092339
dtype: float64}
```

Last create [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index'))
                   0         1         2         3         4         5  \
2016-07-15  0.417022       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2016-07-16  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2016-07-17  0.720324  0.000114  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339       NaN   
2016-07-18  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339  0.186260  0.345561  0.396767   

                   6  
2016-07-15       NaN  
2016-07-16       NaN  
2016-07-17       NaN  
2016-07-18  0.538817
```

Comment: Thank you, a bit modified first step.